# Importing a specific commit of go subdirectory module with same module path as root

Tags: go, go-modules

I am given a repository hosted on a private site, and it looks like this:

```
a-private-git.com/myrepo/
    go/
        go.mod
        go.sum
        bar.go
```

The repository is located at `a-private-git.com/myrepo` and the module file is: (Note that the module itself is actually located at `a-private-git.com/myrepo/go`)

```
module a-private-git.com/myrepo
```

Is it possible to include a specific commit/branch of this repository? Or do I need the provider of the repo to change it?

I've tried:

```
go get a-private-git.com/myrepo@v0.0.0-<commit time>-<commit hash>
> the module is added to go.mod, but when I build I get:
> no required module provides package a-private-git.com/myrepo; to add it: 
>    go get a-private-git.com/myrepo

go get a-private-git.com/myrepo/go@v0.0.0-<commit time>-<commit hash>
> module declares its path as: a-private-git.com/myrepo
>     but was required as: a-private-git.com/myrepo/go

(Based on https://go.dev/doc/modules/managing-source)
go get a-private-git.com/myrepo/go@go/v0.0.0-<commit time>-<commit hash>
> invalid version: unknown revision go/v0.0.0-<commit time>-<commit hash>
```

Comment: Not sure if this fits your needs, but you can just checkout the private repo with your wished commit and use golang"s replace module: https://thewebivore.com/using-replace-in-go-mod-to-point-to-your-local-module/

Answer (score 1):

The easieset way would be to simply 'go get' the commit hash you want:

```
go get a-private-git.com/myrepo@commit_hash
```

Alternatively you can use a branch name to get its latest commit:

```
go get a-private-git.com/myrepo@branch_name
```

Comment: I've already tried that though, and I get "no required module provides package a-private-git.com/myrepo". Seems like if the go.mod is not in the root of the repo, go can't detect it properly?

Comment: As long as the module name matches the directory names it is in, you don't need a go.mod file in the root of the repository. Since it's a private repository you're trying to access, have you made sure you got access to it?